# Minipage margin to zero

Tags: minipage

I need to reduce minipage inner-margins  to zero.

Is there a way to set to zero?
Like in the example below?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\ignorespaces%
\fbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}{100pt}test\end{minipage}}%
\fbox{\noindent\begin{minipage}{100pt}test\end{minipage}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The margin is added by `\fbox` and controlled by length `\fboxsep` (whose default value is 3pt), hence has nothing to do with `minipage` environment. You can use `\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}` (out side the `\fbox`) to set the margin to zero.